# Seurat UMAP visualization result is mirrored after running in two identical environments

Tags: r, seurat, runumap

When I run the same R code in my local computer RStudio (R 4.0.2) and on Code Ocean R 4.0.3, I have two different UMAP visualization results and they are mirrored

[[image]]

[image]

I use Seurat 3.2.0 version in both environments and particularly for umap visualization, here is the line:

```
DimPlot(MU197PDXThgFiltered, reduction = "umap", label = TRUE, label.size = 6, pt.size = 0.5)
```

I can't give a reproducible example, but maybe someone faced this issue before?

Comment: Did you set a seed (e.g. `set.seed(123)` or `seed.use = 123` within the RunUMAP function) before running the `Dimplot()` function?

Comment: yes, I used set.seed(100) before clustering. Still almost mirrored results

Comment: Yeah, they aren't exactly mirrored - the clusters are slightly different e.g. 6, 0, 8 - I think the best way to get an answer on 'why' they're different is to raise an issue on github (https://github.com/satijalab/seurat/issues) or contact someone from Rahul's lab to see if they can provide advice. Also might be worth asking on https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ where you might find others with the same issue

Comment: thank you. I found a comment from them that UMAP can differ depending on OS

Answer (score 3):

I found this on Seurat github:

> The exact location of points on a UMAP plot can chance across
> different computers and OSs. We do our best to minimize any randomness
> to the procedure by fixing the random seed, but some fluctuation
> across systems is inevitable, and nothing to worry about

Other than point locations on UMAP, gene expressions in clusters and cell numbers in them are identical